# Filter and update a ReadOnlyObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, mvvm, filtering

I have an ordinary ObservableCollection that carries my BillDetailsViewModel.
I need to expose this collection to make it bindable to the View, but not alterable from outside the VM.
Here comes the ReadOnlyObservableCollection: pretty handy, pretty simple.
Now I need the ability to filter the results shown.
What I'm doing is dinamically creating a new ReadOnlyObsColl every time the filters list changes, and updating the binding to the ListView ItemsSource, this way:

`this.FilteredBills =
    new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<BillDetailsViewModel>(
        new ObservableCollection<BillDetailsViewModel>(
            this.Bills.Where(b => this.Filter(b))));`

the problem is that, of course, I must manually refresh the binding on the ReadOnlyObsColl every time I make an edit to the collection or an item of the collection.

Is there a better way to do this.
Or is it better if I move all the filtering and sorting logic to the UI layer using an extended list control?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `Edit collection` and `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` doesn't really match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with filtering, it's a good idea to have 2 collections, or 2 sources.

*1st* is for *original* source (it may not be a collection at all naturally, just an example)

*2nd* is a collection that finishes on `UI` via `VM`. That collection can be changed, so `UI` will look like filtered. To reset the filter, simply reload *2nd* collection from the *1st*.

According to the documentation of the [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If changes are made to the underlying collection, the
>   ReadOnlyObservableCollection reflects those changes.

So under the hood you may operate on *real* `ObservableCollection` you have.

In this way you avoid creating new objects every time, and that is good:

1) because you messing up the binding

2) because you pump program's memory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's exactly what I want to achieve, but the problem is that I need to put some sorting-filtering logic between the 2 sources, without breaking the notification chain

Comment: If you don't want to break notification chain, this is a way to go basically. Do not create a new object, as you mess up the binding mechanism therefore notification chain too.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get where you would put the filtering logic in your solution.

Comment: @NalessoSergio: naturraly inside view model. there you have a collection 2 (which is a collection of ui), you remove elements to it to enable filtering. but you have another collection, or in view model again, or on business layer, which is *original one*. so one time filter was reset, you fill collection 2 from *original* one. so the view collection (2) will have again all elements inside.

Comment: ok, but there's something I don't get of your solution: you say I work with an ObservableCollection as coll (1) and a ReadOnlyObservableCollection as (2). But that's what I'm already doing, and it forces me to create a new ReadOnlyObservableCollection everytime I reset the filter.
Or you are suggesting me to use a ObservableCollection as (2) too, but that would allow changes from the outside.

Comment: as says documentation, if you change `ObservableCollection<T>` that is inside Readonly one, Readonly one changes as well. So change non readonly collection, but the collection inside. So in your case you will have. 1 collection original, 2 collection for filtering, 3 readonly collection over 2nd one.

Comment: I got it, haha, didn't think about it, sorry. Yours might be a good solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be breaking MVVM design patterns by using viewmodels as a collection type. I mean, I don't know of many people who adhere to MVVM strict design principles, but following that design (if I understand your question correctly) might help you with your solution.

So I would create a model called "BillDetailsModel":

```
    public class BillDetailsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

      // INSERT YOUR MODEL PROPERTIES

    /// <summary>
    ///     DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    /// </summary>
    public BillDetailsModel()
    {

    }

    #region Property Changed

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and another model that extends Observable Collection called "BillDetailsModels":

```
    public class BillDetailsModels: ObservableCollection<BillDetailsModel>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        /// <summary>
        ///     DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
        /// </summary>
        public BillDetailsModels()
        { 

        }

}
```

The plural would be essentially just an "empty" model that extends both an Observable Collection and your BillDetailsModel.

This way, your viewmodel can now properly manipulate a concrete instantiation of "BillDetailsModels" and filter/extrapolate the data or whatever you need to do.

Cheers!

Comment: Make sure to use RaisePropertyChanged wherever you need to in your ViewModel, and implement INotifyPropertyChanged if needed in your Collections Model

Comment: thank you for you reply. So I shouldn't create ObservableCollection<Model> properties?
I have a question;: why would you create a BillDetailsModel if I already have a BillDetailsViewModel to wrap the Bill Model class?
BillDetailsViewModels just takes the Bill that is read from the DB and exposes additional properties calculated from the basic ones cantained in the simple Bill.
In the end, I can't see any difference between what you suggest and my implementation. Am I missing any aspect?

Comment: What Bill Model Class do you have? If I understand you correctly, you sound like you do have a model class already. That model class should be a wrapper, pulling from your DB whatever you need. I would create though another Model class, that is simply a collection of your BillModel class. This way, your viewModel can manipulate the collection (add, subtract) from that concrete collection. Your view can then bind to your viewmodel's collection (which is a collection of billmodels). Notifications should happen correctly then and your view should be updated properly

Answer (score 0):

Solved creating a custom collection. The implementation is basically a re-implementation of the [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620(v=vs.110).aspx) class, with the benefit of being able to access the private list field. This allowed me to intercept notifications coming from the source [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), apply the filtering logic, create customized [NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), and propagate the event.

---

This is the implementation:

```
[Serializable]
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
public class ReadOnlyObservableCollectionEx<T> : IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where T : class
{
    #region fields

    private readonly ObservableCollection<T> source;
    private IList<T> filteredSource;

    [NonSerialized]
    private Object _syncRoot;

    #endregion

    #region ctor

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollectionEx(ObservableCollection<T> source, IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> filters)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        this.source = source;
        this.filters = filters;

        this.UpdateFiltering();

        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)this.source).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(HandleCollectionChanged);
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this.source).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(HandlePropertyChanged);
    }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollectionEx(ObservableCollection<T> source)
        : this(source, null)
    {
    }

    #endregion ctor

    #region properties

    private IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> filters;
    public IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> Filters
    {
        get { return this.filters; }
        set
        {
            if (this.filters == value & value == null) return;

            this.filters = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange();

            this.UpdateFiltering();
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

    #endregion properties

    #region methods

    private void UpdateFiltering()
    {
        if (this.Filters != null)
            this.filteredSource = this.source.Where(i => this.Filters.All(f => f(i))).ToList();
        else
            this.filteredSource = this.source.ToList();

        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange("Item[]");
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange("Count");
    }

    #endregion methods

    #region implementations

    #region IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.filteredSource.Count; }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.filteredSource[index]; }
    }

    public bool Contains(T value)
    {
        return this.filteredSource.Contains(value);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index)
    {
        this.filteredSource.CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.filteredSource.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int IndexOf(T value)
    {
        return this.filteredSource.IndexOf(value);
    }

    protected IList<T> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.filteredSource;
        }
    }

    bool ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    T IList<T>.this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.filteredSource[index]; }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    void ICollection<T>.Add(T value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void ICollection<T>.Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void IList<T>.Insert(int index, T value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    bool ICollection<T>.Remove(T value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void IList<T>.RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)this.filteredSource).GetEnumerator();
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get
        {
            if (_syncRoot == null)
            {
                ICollection c = this.filteredSource as ICollection;
                if (c != null)
                {
                    _syncRoot = c.SyncRoot;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange<Object>(ref _syncRoot, new Object(), null);
                }
            }
            return _syncRoot;
        }
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (array.Rank != 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if (array.GetLowerBound(0) != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if (index < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if (array.Length - index < Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        T[] items = array as T[];
        if (items != null)
        {
            this.filteredSource.CopyTo(items, index);
        }
        else
        {
            //
            // Catch the obvious case assignment will fail.
            // We can found all possible problems by doing the check though.
            // For example, if the element type of the Array is derived from T,
            // we can't figure out if we can successfully copy the element beforehand.
            //
            Type targetType = array.GetType().GetElementType();
            Type sourceType = typeof(T);
            if (!(targetType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType) || sourceType.IsAssignableFrom(targetType)))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }

            //
            // We can't cast array of value type to object[], so we don't support 
            // widening of primitive types here.
            //
            object[] objects = array as object[];
            if (objects == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }

            int count = this.filteredSource.Count;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    objects[index++] = this.filteredSource[i];
                }
            }
            catch (ArrayTypeMismatchException)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }

    bool IList.IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    bool IList.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.filteredSource[index]; }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void IList.Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private static bool IsCompatibleObject(object value)
    {
        // Non-null values are fine.  Only accept nulls if T is a class or Nullable<U>.
        // Note that default(T) is not equal to null for value types except when T is Nullable<U>. 
        return ((value is T) || (value == null && default(T) == null));
    }

    bool IList.Contains(object value)
    {
        if (IsCompatibleObject(value))
        {
            return this.Contains((T)value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object value)
    {
        if (IsCompatibleObject(value))
        {
            return this.IndexOf((T)value);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void IList.Remove(object value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void IList.RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged

    event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged
    {
        add { this.CollectionChanged += value; }
        remove { this.CollectionChanged -= value; }
    }

    [field: NonSerialized]
    protected virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            this.CollectionChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    void HandleCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                {
                    if (this.Filters != null)
                    {
                        // if there are no filter OR if the added item passes the filter
                        if (this.Filters.All(f => f(e.NewItems[0] as T)))
                        {
                            // add it
                            this.UpdateFiltering(); // TODO: check if there's a way to just add the item
                            var addIndex = this.IndexOf(e.NewItems[0] as T);

                            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, e.NewItems, addIndex));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.filteredSource.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, e.NewItems[0] as T);

                        this.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                {
                    if (this.Filters != null)
                    {
                        // if there are no filter OR if the moved item passes the filter
                        if (this.Filters.All(f => f(e.OldItems[0] as T)))
                        {
                            // if it was already in the filtered list
                            var wasAlreadyContained = this.Contains(e.OldItems[0] as T);
                            int oldIndex = -1;

                            if (wasAlreadyContained)
                                oldIndex = this.IndexOf(e.OldItems[0] as T);

                            this.UpdateFiltering(); // TODO: check if there's a way to just add the item
                            var newIndex = this.IndexOf(e.OldItems[0] as T);

                            if (wasAlreadyContained)
                                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, e.OldItems, newIndex, oldIndex));
                            else
                                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, e.OldItems, newIndex));
                        }
                        // if the moved item doesn't pass the filter but it's contained
                        else if (this.Contains(e.OldItems[0] as T))
                        {
                            // remove it
                            var removeIndex = this.IndexOf(e.OldItems[0] as T);
                            this.filteredSource.RemoveAt(removeIndex);

                            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, e.OldItems, removeIndex));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.filteredSource.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                        this.filteredSource.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, e.NewItems[0] as T);

                        this.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                {
                    if (this.Filters != null)
                    {
                        // if the item is contained (passes the filter)
                        if (this.Filters.All(f => f(e.OldItems[0] as T)))
                        {
                            // remove it
                            var removeIndex = this.IndexOf(e.OldItems[0] as T);
                            this.filteredSource.RemoveAt(removeIndex);

                            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, e.OldItems, removeIndex));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.filteredSource.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);

                        this.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                {
                    if (this.Filters != null)
                    {
                        // if the item that has been replaced is contained (passes the filter)
                        if (this.Filters.All(f => f(e.OldItems[0] as T)))
                        {
                            // remove it
                            var replaceIndex = this.IndexOf(e.OldItems[0] as T);
                            this.filteredSource.RemoveAt(replaceIndex);

                            // if the new one is allowed
                            if (this.Filters.All(f => f(e.NewItems[0] as T)))
                            {
                                // replace it
                                this.filteredSource.Insert(replaceIndex, e.NewItems[0] as T);

                                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, e.NewItems, e.OldItems, replaceIndex));
                            }
                            else // if the new one it's not allowed
                                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, e.OldItems, replaceIndex));
                        }
                        else // if the replaced item is not contained
                        {
                            // but the new one is allowed
                            if (this.Filters.All(f => f(e.NewItems[0] as T)))
                            {
                                // add it
                                this.UpdateFiltering(); // TODO: check if there's a way to just add the item
                                var addIndex = this.IndexOf(e.NewItems[0] as T);

                                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, e.NewItems, addIndex));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.filteredSource.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                        this.filteredSource.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, e.NewItems[0] as T);

                        this.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                {
                    this.UpdateFiltering();
                    this.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                    break;
                }

            default:
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(@"Unknown collection action: " + e.Action);
        }
    }

    #endregion INotifyCollectionChanged

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { this.PropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { this.PropertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    [field: NonSerialized]
    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    public virtual void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged

    #endregion implementations
}
```